# App crashes in getResources() after changing language

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, fragment

My app crashes after I change language of the device. During changing the language the app is running in background. Error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Error message point to this call (inside of `SherlockFragment`)

```
tv.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.d));
```

what can I do to avoid this error?

my folder structure is:

```
   res/
     values/strings.xml
     values-de/strings.xml
     values-fr/strings.xml
```

full log:

```
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at    com.myapp.countdown.CountdownFragment$1.onTick(CountdownFragment.java:58)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-30 23:41:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(17414):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building the resources folder according to Google specs:

```
    MyProject/
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

Because  Android automatically uses the resources from the language the device is using. 
See more here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Can't do anything else but agree with @SQLiteNoob, follow the Google specification and read mor on localization on given link. You seem to not follow the specification(resource structure) and therefore you are given the NPE.

Comment: actually I have this structure. Maybe its related to fragment/activity? because it happens if app is in background.

Comment: If you call a string that isn't in the desired language, you could get an NPE from it as well - checked that?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your string in *values* directory then it must work properly because Android at first tries to adjust strings from the directory created for particular language and if the directory does not exist, Android expects *values* to be the last one containing your string.

The only possible scenario for getting NullPointerException is that you created *string* in *values* directory for particular language and did not provide the default *values* with this string or the *values* directory with language you switched your phone to.

Please, provide us with stackTrace. If your app was in background, then it might have been terminated by the system and your NPE does not concern getting a string.

Comment: I have 4 languages, en, fr, ru and de. and my dir structure is:
res/
 values/
 values-de/
 values-fr/
 values-ru

Comment: Please, invoke the situation and paste your full stack trace.

Comment: edit meassage.... but I assume NullPointer is not about string resource, but activity... could it be?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comment to my answer - if you call a string that you have in `values-de/` but when the phone is in, say, Russian, it will throw the exception if the same string isn't found in `values-ru/`

Comment: 1. Please, add your string (with name "d") to every values directory and check.
2. If exception still occurs, please paste the code from CountdownFragment (onTick method) and describe in which fragment's lifecycle method you attempt getting your string. And what is actually your CountdownTimer doing?